# Vector space question with linear forms

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

If I have vector space of $n$ degree polynomials with real coefficients and $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$, and inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^1 f'(x) g'(x) dx$, how do I show that there is unique $f$ such that $-\int_0^1 f''(x)g(x)dx = g(1/2)$ for all $g \in V$?

For the left hand side, if I apply integration by parts, I get $-\int_0^1 f''(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^1 f'(x)g'(x)dx$ and if I integrate by parts again, I get the expression $\int_0^1 f''(x)g(x) - f(x)g''(x) = 0$. The integrand is $\frac{d}{dx} ( f'g - g'f)$ but I dont know if this is on the right track? Do I need a brute force approach and assume $f(x) = a_nx^n + ... a_1 x$ and try to do something with coefficients?

Comment: Any finite-dimensional normed space is a Hilbert space, so that Riesz representation theorem  applies.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

The map
$$V\rightarrow \mathbb R,\quad g\mapsto g(1/2)$$
is a linear form and by integration by parts
$$-\int_0^1 f''(x)g(x)dx=\int_0^1 f'(x)g'(x)dx=\langle f,g \rangle $$
so use [the Riesz representation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem).

Comment: I dont quite see how that helps? If $f'(x)g'(x)dx=\langle f,g \rangle $ how does that relate with $g(1/2)$? We know that $g(1-1/2) = g(1) - g(1/2) = - g(1/2)$?

Comment: I don't know that much about Analysis. :(

Comment: @B.S. We can simply learn what we need from dear Sami! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Yes of course! :+)

Comment: Bumpppppppppppppp? Still dont know how to relate the inner product with $g(1/2)$